# How should I go about the shoulders on this exceptionally noodly character?

Tags: topology, retopology

[image: A screenshot of the shoulders of my character, in the middle of retopology. The body and arms are long, slender, and cylindrical.]

Everything else i've figured out about other shoulders really isn't helping here. I'm going to rig and pose this after this step is done

Answer (score 1):

Cut a hole in your cylinder (maybe use less vertices by the way):

[image]

Extrude inwards and right click > *LoopTools > Circle* (you need to enable the *LoopTools* addon):

[image]

Extrude on the axis:

[image]

Bevel if the transition is supposed to be smooth:

[image]